# Make Visual Studio Code recognize the classes in the Zend Framework Library

Tags: zend-framework, visual-studio-code

When I open the IndexController with Visual Studio Code it doesn't find any of the classes in the Zend Framework Library which are located in the library/Zend folder.

Whenever I click on Zend_Controller_Action and press CTRL and SPACE, I expect VSC to show me the suggestions, but it doesn't.

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {[...]}
```

Intelliphense or whatever that plugin is called is installed already.

It's working in netbeans though, whilst also failing in Zend Studio...PhpStorm...

So I guess there must be some setting, right?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I just had the same problem, on a system that uses a fairly old version of Zend, using a VS Code with the Inteliphense extension installed, and someone helped me solve it like so:

- in VS Code, open Settings
- search for "Intelephense Environment include paths"
- press "Add Item" to add the following two paths :

  ```
    /usr/share/php7.2-common/ZendFramework-1.12.20/library/
    /usr/share/php7.2-common/
  ```